# unable to find the place to change origins in google api console

Tags: google-api, google-plus, mismatch

I am getting a Origin Mismatch error on Google Plus. Attaching the image below:

[image]

Read online about this:

1) In the [document](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/oauth2-dev/lSN89BVesmI) someone has mentioned that origin and scope should match. One has http and another has https. I am wondering where exactly in my Google API Console I can edit and change those items?

2) [Here](https://github.com/alexyoung/dailyjs-backbone-tutorial/issues/7) also someone has mentioned the same thing but I am wondering where can I find that place in google api console. The screenshot mentioned over here looks old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to [console.developers.google.com](https://console.developers.google.com/), select the project, and go to credentials under APIs & Auth. Then edit the settings for the particular client ID.

[image]